# PHP array_filter with get_class filter

Tags: php

I have an array of objects, and I want to check if a certain classname is in it. So I tried:

```
$all_classnames = array_filter($obj_array, 'get_class');
$found = in_array("classname_to_test", $all_classnames);
```

Only, $all_classnames still holds the original object array instead of an array of classnames (through get_class). Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (which transforms the input array based on the callback function) instead of `array_filter`:

```
$all_classnames = array_map('get_class', $obj_array);
```

Note that `array_map` takes its arguments in the reverse order than the other array functions that use a callback because PHP.

Comment: Perfect, small thinking error there. Thanks! Will set this as my answer as soon as they let me :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not how the [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function works. It just filters your array if the callback returns `false` it will remove the element from the array.

What you need is [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$all_classnames = array_map('get_class', $obj_array);
```